# How to listen an event only within a specific component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, slider, event-listener

I am using this code as a base to create a touchable slider in ReactJS so that the user can change the sliders with their fingers, and it works fine, however I need the events to be triggered only within the carousel (`track div`), what is not happening here. In this example the events are triggered from any part of the screen (you can try it on the blue part).

Is there a way I can do this, make the eventlisteners work only within a specific component (which here is just a div)?

Remember, I'm using React, this is just an example.

```js
const track = document.querySelector('.track');
let initialPosition = null;
let moving = false;
let transform = 0;

const gestureStart = (e) => {
  initialPosition = e.pageX;
  moving = true;
  const transformMatrix = window.getComputedStyle(track).getPropertyValue('transform');
  if (transformMatrix !== 'none') {
    transform = parseInt(transformMatrix.split(',')[4].trim());
  }
}

const gestureMove = (e) => {
  if (moving) {
    const currentPosition = e.pageX;
    const diff = currentPosition - initialPosition;
    track.style.transform = `translateX(${transform + diff}px)`;  
  }
};

const gestureEnd = (e) => {
  moving = false;
}

if (window.PointerEvent) {
  window.addEventListener('pointerdown', gestureStart);

  window.addEventListener('pointermove', gestureMove);

  window.addEventListener('pointerup', gestureEnd);  
} else {
  window.addEventListener('touchdown', gestureStart);

  window.addEventListener('touchmove', gestureMove);

  window.addEventListener('touchup', gestureEnd);  
  
  window.addEventListener('mousedown', gestureStart);

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', gestureMove);

  window.addEventListener('mouseup', gestureEnd);  
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.carousel {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}
.carousel .track {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  touch-action: none;
}

.carousel .track .card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <h2>It shouldn't work here outside of the carousel</h2>
    <div class="track">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you add listeners to the `carousel` element? You are listening for the events on the whole `window` that is why is works everywhere you touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the event listener to any dom element, not just the `window`. For example, if you open a console here, you can do:

```
document.querySelector('#left-sidebar').addEventListener('mousemove', e => console.log(e))
```

This will log movement only over the left nav on the page.

For react components, you can get a reference to the dom element using a `ref`, and attach the listener with `useEffect`. Example:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      console.log("moving in the blue box", e.x, e.y);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div ref={ref} style={blueBox} />
      <div style={orangeBox} />
    </div>
  );
}

const box = { minWidth: "300px", minHeight: "300px" };
const blueBox = { ...box, backgroundColor: "cornflowerblue" };
const orangeBox = { ...box, backgroundColor: "coral" };
```

Answer (score 1):

The preferable and safest way to attach an event listener to the specific DOM element in React is by using JSX dedicated properties, i.e. `onMouseDown`, `onMouseMove`, `onMouseUp`. In your case the React component must look like:

```
export default function App() {

  /**
   * This is where you must define your listeners: 
   * gestureStart, gestureMove, gestureEnd
   *
   */


  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="carousel">
        <h2>It shouldn't work here outside of the carousel</h2>
        <div
          onMouseDown={gestureStart}
          onMouseMove={gestureMove}
          onMouseUp={gestureEnd}
          className="track"
        >
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You is adding the event to window which is the whole thing add them to track only

```
xport default function App() {
const track = React.useRef();
  /**
   * This is where you must define your listeners: 
   * onMouseDown, gestureMove, gestureEnd
   *
   */
 
React.useEffect(()=>{

if (window.PointerEvent && track.current) {
  track.current.addEventListener('pointerdown', gestureStart);

  track.current.addEventListener('pointermove', gestureMove);

  track.addEventListener('pointerup', gestureEnd);  
} else {
  track.addEventListener('touchdown', gestureStart);

  track.addEventListener('touchmove', gestureMove);

  track.addEventListener('touchup', gestureEnd);  
  
  track.addEventListener('mousedown', gestureStart);

  track.addEventListener('mousemove', gestureMove);

  track.addEventListener('mouseup', gestureEnd);  
}

},[]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="carousel">
        <h2>It shouldn't work here outside of the carousel</h2>
        <div
          ref={track}
        >
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
          <div className="card"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Make sure to add them event to `track.current`